# Typesafe Config Library unusable in Intellij Scala worksheet

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, typesafe-config

I am using ficus and typesafe config to manage configurations.

I want to use Intellij's scala worksheet in this project but when I try the following code:

```
import what.ever.ApplicationSetting

ApplicationSetting.aws.accessKey
```

However I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at some.thing.A$A11$A$A11.get$$instance$$res0(testRes.sc:3)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(testRes.sc:11)
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'aws'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:147)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:206)
    at net.ceedubs.ficus.readers.StringReader$$anon$1.read(StringReader.scala:7)
    at net.ceedubs.ficus.readers.StringReader$$anon$1.read(StringReader.scala:6)
    at what.ever.ApplicationSetting$$anon$1.read(ApplicationSetting.scala:24)
```

The content of `application.conf` is the following:

```
package what.ever

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import net.ceedubs.ficus.Ficus._
import net.ceedubs.ficus.readers.ArbitraryTypeReader._

object ApplicationSetting {

  val env = sys.env.getOrElse("DEV_ENV", "default")
  val config = {
    ConfigFactory.defaultOverrides
      .withFallback(ConfigFactory.load(env))
      .withFallback(ConfigFactory.load)
  }

  case class AWS(accessKey: String,
                 secretKey: String)

  val aws = config.as[AWS]("aws")

}
```

I find it strange because the same code did work in the scala console.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

In case you want to test the code checkout this [repo](https://gitlab.com/vascoosx/restester/tree/master).

Answer (score 2):

A workaround I found was to load the configuration file in another way.
First change the configuration file to something like `myAppConf.conf` this is to avoid configuration files disappearing from merge strategies.

```
package what.ever

import java.io.File
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import net.ceedubs.ficus.Ficus._
import net.ceedubs.ficus.readers.ArbitraryTypeReader._

object ApplicationSetting {

  val confPath = getClass.getResource("/myAppConf.conf") 
  val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(confPath.getPath)).resolve()

  case class AWS(accessKey: String,
                 secretKey: String)

  val aws = config.as[AWS]("aws")

}
```

Comment: I can't offer much help but sometimes when I run into trouble with worksheets in Intellij I go to repl or [Ammonite](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/#Ammonite-REPL) the later provides nice enhanced repl and easy way to load libraries.

Comment: Ammonite still has difficulty adding classpaths. So in some cases it can not be a replacement. The repl is OK though.